# Where Do I Find The Issuer URL In Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am trying to add Active Directory Authentication to my Azure App Service.

The AD I am using is in a different tenant to the App Service so I need to use Advanced Settings instead of Express (where it creates things for you).

One of the fields is "Issuer Url" and the pop up help says

> "Issuer URL for your Active Directory, TenantId of your Active
>   Directory can be obtained by PowerShell command Get-AzureAccount or by
>   browsing to your Directory from the management portal"

Where do I find the "Issuer Url" in the portal?

Comment: Seems that whatever I put in the Issuer URL, it always looks in the same TenantId as the AppId.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

On the **App registrations** page, click on the **Endpoints** button at the top, then copy the **WS-FEDERATION SIGN-ON ENDPOINT** URL but remove the /wsfed ending from the URL. The end result should look like https://login.microsoftonline.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000. The domain name may be different for a sovereign cloud. This will serve as the Issuer URL.

[image]

Comment: Note that is is only correct for v2 tokens. V1 tokens have `https://sts.windows.net/your-tenant-id` as issuer URI.

Comment: From the documentation on [az webapp auth update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/auth?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_auth_update), the comment on the parameter `--aad-token-issuer-url` states *Get the "issuer" from the JSON at //.well-known/openid-configuration.* . This JSON is provided by the URL, see the screenshot above,  under the end point *OpenID Connect metadata document*

Comment: Just for reference: In my case, the Azure portal gave me this on the WebApp Edit Identity Provider screen: `https://sts.windows.net/{DirectoryTenantGUID}/v2.0`.