# Can't connect ASP.NET MVC to Azure AD with OIDC

Tags: c#, .net, azure, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I am trying to set up an SSO sign in to a ASP.NET MVC 5 application (.NET 4.8) with OpenID Connect. I'm using Azure Active Directory. The application is a brand new project made for testing purposes, and the only change I introduced to scaffolded code is in **Startup.Auth.cs**:

```
// automatically added usings:
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;

// in public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) method:
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = "{ClientId of AAD App}",
                ClientSecret = "{Secret generated for the AAD app}",
                CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-microsoft"),
                MetadataAddress = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration",
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Directory (tenant) ID}/v2.0"
                }
            });
```

If I set `ValidateIssuer` to `false`, everything works fine - I manage to sign into the application with my organization email. But as soon as I set it to `true`, I start getting the following error:

> IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer: '[PII is hidden]'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidIssuer: '[PII is hidden]' or validationParameters.ValidIssuers: '[PII is hidden]'.

I tried changing the `ValidIssuer` to all options mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57665008/where-do-i-find-the-issuer-url-in-azure-active-directory) SO thread, but nothing works. The current `ValidIssuer` is the URL given in the `MetadataAddress` above, with concrete *Directory (tenant) ID* of the registered app.

As far as the registered AAD app goes, I've set both *Access tokens (used for implicit flows)* and *ID tokens (used for implicit and hybrid flows)* to `true` and *Supported account types* to `Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)`.

Any idea what I'm not getting here?

Comment: I think you need to set the Authority option inside OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions to the same value as the ValidIssuer in TokenValidationParameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bad tenant ID after all.

I realized it by setting `IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII` to `true` in `Startup.Auth.cs`, as seen in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55027625/2975357